# SMS 120 characters length limit

Tags: sms, limit

I've tried to send SMS using C# and GSMComm and mCoreLib libraries; but the problem is that the SMS length is limited to 120 characters in 7 bit encoding, and 53 characters in 16 bit Unicode encoding.
What could be the problem? Though the documentation stated 160 for 7 bit encoding and 70 for 16 bit unicode.
Also I noticed that the french accent characters are sent using the 7 bit encoding, is this normal?

I use Sony Ericsson W200 and K320.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a range of accented characters listed in the GSM 7-bit alphabet which tends to be enough to cope with most French words. However GSM 7-bit doesn't include all the characters that European languages require.

You're correct that 160 characters for 7-bit and 70 for 16-bit Unicode (and 140 for 8-bit Unicode while we're talking about it) should be the maximum characters for a single SMS message.

It sounds like the libraries are getting in your way. When you say it's limited, are you meaning that sending messages through the library truncates your message at 120 characters?

I've not used those libraries myself but thought I'd offer some reassurance that your assumptions were correct and the behaviour you're experiencing shouldn't be the maximum length of message you can send.

Good luck!